# Get difference between two dates in Years

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, rounding, datediff

I am working with a table that has StartDate and EndDate fields.  I need to find difference between then in years.

Example:
StartDate = 1/1/2017
EndDate   = 12/31/2017

I expect Result = 1 for the date difference.

Also, I'd like to round it to nearest whole number.

Example:
StartDate = 1/1/2017
EndDate   = 11/30/2017

I expect Result = 1 for the date difference.

Using datediff function, I am able to get the result, but it isn't rounding to nearest whole number.

Example query:
I am getting 6 years even though 65 months / 12 would be less than 5.5:

```
select (DATEDIFF(yy, '01/01/2016', '5/31/2021')
+ CASE WHEN abs(DATEPART(day, '01/01/2016') - DATEPART(day, '05/31/2021')) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
select (DATEDIFF(mm, '01/01/2016', '05/31/2021')
+ CASE WHEN abs(DATEPART(day, '01/01/2016') - DATEPART(day, '05/31/2021')) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `ROUND` function?

Comment: I did try round function, but it keeps returning 0 for above query instead of 1.  I want to see 0 if less than .5 is returned and 1 if more than .5 returned.  I can either seem to do 1.

Comment: I just realized my mistake.  I was not using round function correctly:  I think this will work:  select round(1.3, 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far following query seems to be working okay.  My mistake was I dividing by 12 instead of 12.0 for rounding to work correctly.  Who knew! :

```
select 
Round((DATEDIFF(mm, '01/01/2016', '07/1/2017')
    + CASE WHEN abs(DATEPART(day,  '01/01/2016') - DATEPART(day, '06/30/2017')) > 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 12.0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME = '1-1-2017', 
        @enddate DATETIME = '12-31-2018'
SELECT @startdate as StartDate, @enddate as EndDate,
 DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startdate, @enddate)
   -
 (CASE
   WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 
           DATEDIFF(YEAR, @startdate,@enddate), @startdate)
       > @enddate THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 END) 'Date difference in Years'
```

Use this code, I hope it will help you.

Comment: Issue with your code is if you use 07-01-2018 as your @enddate, it will still give you 1 year instead of 2.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit old but when using Oracle SQL Developer you can use the following. Just add your Dates below. I was using DateTime. This was used to get years between 0 and 10.

`TRUNC((MONTHS_BETWEEN(<DATE_ONE>, <DATE_TWO>) * 31) / 365) > 0 and TRUNC((MONTHS_BETWEEN(<DATE_ONE>, <DATE_TWO>) * 31) / 365) < 10`